# CSS Buttons (w/ Background but need bevel)

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
<input type="submit"/>

<style>
input {
  background: url(tick.png) bottom left no-repeat;
  padding-left: 18px;
}
</style>
```

But the bevel goes away, how can I add an icon to submit button and keep the bevel?
Edit: I want it to look like the browser default.

Answer (score 3):

Using <.input type="submit" /> with a background will look different depending on what browser / OS you're on.

If you want to keep the browser styles, you could use the button element, which allows HTML inside the tag:

```
<button type="submit"><img src="image.gif" /> Text</button>
or 
<button type="submit"><span class="icon"></span> Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use border-style outset:

border: 2px outset #cccccc;

Comment: I really want it to look like the browser default.

Answer (score 1):

For a true button effect, I also like to introduce a hover or a focus style. Similar to what @Roburg has mentioned, I normally do something like:

```
input#button {
    border: 2px outset rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

input#button:focus {
    border: 2px inset rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

This will give the illusion that the button has been pressed even though it isn't a true button, per se.

Comment: @Steve - yeah, that was a typo out of habit - I usually use divs for buttons. thanks for the catch ;)

Comment: Why do you usually use divs for buttons? That seems... back-assward.

Comment: Normally for Ajax and style issues. Use a div, JavaScript event handler, CSS styling, and then gracefully fall back to a standard input button if JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

My old shop used to rock the input type="image" syntax - it works as Submit. As one of my favorite poker people likes to say, "all you can eat, baby!" - anything you want to put there as a graphic.

Answer (score 0):

Use border.  For example:

```
INPUT.button {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #999999 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #999999 1px solid;
    FONT-SIZE: 11px;
    BACKGROUND: url(tick.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    BORDER-LEFT: #999999 1px solid;
    CURSOR: pointer;
    COLOR: #333333;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #999999 1px solid
}

<input type="submit" class="button" />
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't look like the same button (Firefox).

Comment: Can I ask your reasoning for upper case?